# Dataframe groupby timestamp interval, non-overlapping, and sum of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, dask

I'm trying to group entries for a given interval of timestamp, non-overlapping, if their values of another column are above a certain threshold.

Here follows a reduced example.

I have a dataframe as such:

```
     timestamp      col1  col2 col3  col4
0   2317614314  1.551823     1    4    44
1   2317614409  1.206112     3    3    25
2   2317614429  1.022747     2    3    48
3   2317614608  2.082569     3    3    59
4   2317622053  2.260681     1    2    15
5   2317622208  2.355770     2    4    46
```

I want to group the data according to the following rules:

- Rows are only in one group
- Rows that are in a interval in relation the first timestamp
- The sum of the values of col1 have to be greater than a threshold

An example:

Let's say the interval is 200 and the threshold is 4:

- Rows 0,1,2 are in the interval of 200 after the first timestamp (2317614314<=timestamp<=2317614314+200)
- The sum of col1 is less than the threshold (1.551823+1.206112+1.022747<4)
- So it ignore the row 0 and continues
- Rows 1,2,3 are in the interval of 200 after the first timestamp (2317614409<=timestamp<=2317614409+200)
- The sum of col1 is above the threshold (1.206112+1.022747+2.082569>4)
- As the rows can't be in more than one group it would then start in row 4
- Rows 4,5 are in the interval of 200 after the first timestamp (2317622053<=timestamp<=2317622053+200)
- The sum of col1 is above the threshold (2.260681+2.355770>4)

So in the end I would end up with 2 groups:

- Rows 1,2,3
- Rows 4,5

Some considerations:

- I am using Dask
- Solutions using Pandas are more than welcome
- The timestamp is in ps, hence not using "datetime64" as pandas only support ns precision

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got a working solution.
Posting for posteriority.

```
@dask.delayed
def get_groups(df, interval, threshold):

    start_time = df['timestamp'].min()
    end_time = start_time + interval
    current_group = []
    current_sum = 0

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['time'] > end_time:
            if current_sum >= threshold:
            yield pandas.DataFrame(current_group)
            
            current_group = []
            current_sum = 0
            start_time = row['timestamp']
            end_time = start_time + interval
    
        current_group.append(row)
        current_sum += row['col1']

    if current_sum >= threshold:
        yield pandas.DataFrame(current_group)

interval=100
threshold=4
    
result = dask.bag.from_delayed(get_groups(df, interval, threshold))
```

This seems to work well.
If anyone has any suggestion, don't hesitate.

EDIT: This is very slow, if anyone has a better solution please add it.

Comment: It seems I have to wait 2 days to accept it